# 'nil' when trying to convert a DataSnapshot to a DataModel array

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to put the data from a Firebase snapshot into a data model array, but I'm getting nil values. Please, suggest what is wrong.

My data model:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class OtherObjectsDataModel {
    var date: String?
    var email: String?
    var name: String?
    var category: String?
    var type: String?
    var lat: Double?
    var lon: Double?
    var city: String?
    var address: String?
    var description: String?
    var imgURI: String?
    var imgName: String?
    
    var ref = Database.database().reference()
    
    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            let date = dict["Date"] as? String
            let email = dict["Email"] as? String
            let name = dict["Name"] as? String
            let category = dict["Category"] as? String
            let type = dict["Type"] as? String
            let lat = dict["Latitude"] as? Double
            let lon = dict["Longitude"] as? Double
            let city = dict["City"] as? String
            let address = dict["Address"] as? String
            let description = dict["Description"] as? String
            let imgURI = dict["imgURI"] as? String
            let imgName = dict["imgName"] as? String
        }
   
    }
    
}
```

In the following function I want to access the data and to put in into a data model array, but I'm getting nil values

```
     func getByAutoID(){
            let objectsRef = ref.child("OtherObjects")
            objectsRef.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
                if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                    for child in result {
    
                        let orderID = child.key as String //get autoID
                        print(orderID, "ID")
                        let childByAutoID = objectsRef.child("\(orderID)").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
                            for list in snapshot.children {
                                print(list) //returns values
                                let aList = OtherObjectsDataModel(snapshot: list as! DataSnapshot)
                                print(aList.address) //returns nil
                            }
    
    
                        })
    
                    }
                }
    
    
            })
        }
```

I tried also another way, but the "otherObjectsData" array is also empty after executing the function

```
 var otherObjectsData:[OtherObjects] = []
   func getByAutoID(){
        let objectsRef = ref.child("OtherObjects")
        objectsRef.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for child in result {

                    let orderID = child.key as String //get autoID
                    print(orderID, "ID")
                    let childByAutoID = objectsRef.child("\(orderID)").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
                        if let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
                            for item in snapshotValue {
                                let address = snapshotValue["Address"] as! String
                                let city = snapshotValue["City"] as! String
                                let date = snapshotValue["Date"] as! String
                                let desc = snapshotValue["Description"] as! String
                                let email = snapshotValue["Email"] as! String
                                let imgUri = snapshotValue["ImgURI"] as! String
                                let lat = snapshotValue["Latitude"] as! Double
                                let lon = snapshotValue["Longitude"] as! Double
                                let name = snapshotValue["Name"] as! String
                                let category = snapshotValue["ObjectCategory"] as! String
                                let type = snapshotValue["ObjectType"] as! String
                                let imgname = snapshotValue["imgName"] as! String

                                var tempObj = OtherObjects(date: date, email: email, name: name, category: category, type: type, lat: lat, lon: lon, city: city, address: address, description: desc, imgURI: imgUri, imgName: imgname)
                                self.otherObjectsData.insert(tempObj, at: 0)
                            }
                           
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Try replacing `if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {` with `if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {`.

Comment: the same result

Comment: `init(snapshot: DataSnapshot)` assign not value to its property? There is nothing in the `{}` of the `if let`... It's just creating local variable. `let email = dict["Email"] as? String` -> `self.email = dict["Email"] as? String` and so on.

Comment: @Larme I changed the model, but it's still 'nil'

Comment: Clarity is needed. We don't know what your Firebase looks like,  include it; what are the results of `objectsRef.child("\(orderID)").observe(.value,`. Also, why cast it to a Dictionary? All of the values in a snapshot can be accessed with `.childSnapshot(forPath:`. What is the purpose of the `for...loop`? Then, `let childByAutoID = objectsRef.child("\(orderID)").observe(.value` does not return a childByAutoID, it returns a reference to the node; since nothing is being done with that, it's unneeded. See [Lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events)

Comment: `if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {`: print `snapshotValue`, also print `dict["Address"]`, is it nil? Is it a String? It's unclear. You need to debug. Each time you do `as?`, check if it's really that type. Each time you do a `if let value = ... as? SomeType { something }` add else { print("It's not a SomeType")  }, or use breakpoints. It's lacking infos and debug. And we can't do it for you, we can't guess.